# Is it possible to use a Li-po battery from an old Kindle to build a battery pack?

Tags: batteries, charging

I want to do this cool [Instructable project](https://www.instructables.com/Use-Old-Mobile-Batteries-to-Power-Anything-Almost/) which uses recycled mobile phone and other batteries to make external battery packs.

I am not sure if or how I could use the batteries I got from some old Kindle Paperwhites, e.g. [this one](https://www.ebay.com/itm/265517396662?chn=ps&mkevt=1&mkcid=28&srsltid=Ad5pg_GD-Q3BC-3cKOYT7zYys7LXHBvZOQhOr45yiQ2ZLrEKPn7kkLnsVuY).

Do I need to dismantle the batteries more and remove some charging circuit before I can hook it up to the charging circuit recommended in the project, e.g [this](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/4001232373142.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.main.1.6fa226b5ec0UvV&algo_pvid=00e55872-79fd-4995-854d-d68bb9263d53&algo_exp_id=00e55872-79fd-4995-854d-d68bb9263d53-0&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2210000015391249308%22%7D&pdp_npi=3%40dis%21EUR%210.57%210.53%21%21%21%21%21%40211be17616770996157898300d06c2%2110000015391249308%21sea%21LU%214383616264&curPageLogUid=p3REDAWQnZIU&gatewayAdapt=glo2fra)?

I would appreciate advice so I can avoid blowing things up when working on it with my daughter.

Comment: Do NOT disassemble the battery!  You can simply use the (+) & (-) terminals directly.  Be aware that a single cell like you linked to is unlikely to be very useful.  However, if you have s number of similar or identical cells, first ensure they are all at the same voltage.  Then simply connect them all in parallel.

Comment: @DwayneReid "Then simply connect them all in parallel" except not quite as simple as that when charging, of course - a balance charger would be required.

Comment: @Polynomial: I **did** mention "similar or identical cells".

Comment: This looks pretty much the same as a mobile phone battery. Which makes sense because they are the same kind of device. I expect that any project designed for a "mobile phone battery" would also work with this one.

Comment: thank you @DwayneReid, Polynomial, user253751, extremely helpful. I will not disassemble! Indeed, 1420 mAh is not a whole lot, but its more a fun project with my daughter to power some LED Butterfly and other project we made, for which it could work a short while. Thanks a lot again.